# No 3G connection in HTC Desire 500

Tags: htc-desire, 3g

I am not able to receive 3G network (the area has excellent 3g coverage) on my HTC desire 500. I have activated 3g on my carrier. It receives only EDGE 'E' Symbol but when I select WCDMA only the symbol changes to G for few seconds and entire network is lost, I tried with two different carriers. Should I need to add more details like my carrier name , APN settings for this question ?

Comment: ok seems like folks share there carrier name mine is TATA DOCOMO , I tried with Airtel too but same issue. Phone was brought in India and not in US.

Comment: You select `WCDMA only` and in `network operator` try changing manual and also simultaneously search in another 3g enabled phone. Check whether you able to see your mobile operator name.

Comment: @above no doesn't work

Comment: what doesn't work? Can you able to see the operator name in your phone? What about the other? Is both phones showing the same operator name